# union of two connect sets in particular case

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A,B \subset X$ are connected and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A^- \cap B \neq \emptyset$ ($A^-$ is closure of $A$) now prove or disprove that $A\cup B$ is connected.

I cannot prove this is connected. For counterexample I think that if $B  \subset A^\prime $ ($A^\prime$ is limit point of A) it is true. So must $B \nsubseteq A^\prime$ .

Comment: Do you know that if $C$ is connected, and $C \subset E \subset \overline{C}$, then $E$ is connected?

Comment: Yes I know . but in this question we how use this?

Comment: Instead of $A$, look at a set $A'$ such that $A' \cup B = A\cup B$ and that you can use a theorem to deduce that $A'\cup B$ is connected.

Comment: Why $A^\prime \cup B = A \cup$  B?

Comment: You pick an $A'$ such that the equality holds.

Comment: it is not true . consider in plane  .a cycle (B)without boundary point and a tangent line (A) in a point .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But don't forget that we have the condition $\overline{A}\cap B \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think your choice of notation "pick an $A'$" could be a source of confusion, seeing as the OP uses $A'$ for the derived set of $A.$

Comment: @bof Duh. That didn't register with me. Indeed, that would explain the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A \cup B$ is partitioned in two open sets, $U,V$, such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $U \cup V = A \cup B$.

$U = U' \cap (A \cup B)$

$V = V' \cap (A \cup B)$

where $U',V'$ are open in $X$.

One of these, say $ U$, contain the limit point $b \in B$. So, because $B$ is connected, $B \subset U$ (otherwise, if $V \cap B \neq \emptyset$ we would have two open sets in $B$, $U \cap B = U' \cap B$ and $V \cap B = V' \cap B$ disjoint, non empty and covering the connected $B$).

But, $U \cap A$ is not empty, since $U$ is open containing the limit point. And by the same argument, $A \subset U$, and $V = \emptyset$.

Comment: In this question what is $T_0  \ and \ T_w$?

Comment: We have $T_1$ and $T_2$ being $A$ and $B$ ($W$ with just two elements) and the central piece $T_0$ is the open, connected set cointaining $b \in B$ limit point of $A$

Comment: $T_1 \cap T_2 = \emptyset$ and we can not use above theorem

Comment: This is not a hypothesis! We just need that the intersections with $T_0$ non-empty.

Comment: Why $T_0 \cup T_1 \cup  T_2 = A \cup B$  ?

Comment: Trying to fix the problem that $T_0 \cup A \cup B \neq A \cup B$, I realized that the problem is much more simple and can be solved in a more elementary way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25716/discussion-between-amir-bahadory-and-joao-dos-reis).

Comment: I can't understand why you define $U^ \prime and V^ \prime$?and why $U^ \prime and V^ \prime$ are exist ?